# is there some difference between "an official" and "an officer"

Tags: meaning, differences, connotation

if I use the word "official" as a noun, then does it have some difference with the word "officer" ??

Sample sentence:

> There are three major officers, head official, deputy official and other officer along with the people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. An officer:

> 1. a person who is in a position of authority in the armed forces: army / air- force / naval officers
> 2. a person who is in a position of authority in the government or a large organization
> 3. (used as a form of address) = POLICE-OFFICER
> 4. a title for a police officer
>      <sub>[Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/officer)</sub>

B. An official:

> 1. [Noun](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/official_2) (often in compounds) a person who is in a position of authority in a large organization. For example, My father has been an economic official in Vina-milk company in Vietnam.
> 2. [Adjective.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/official_1) Connected with a work of some person who has a position of authority. For example, as a financial manager my father has official responsibility to monitor all financial activities and movements of the money in his company.

Answer (score 0):

An officer is a person who works in any of the disciplined forces or government.

An official is a high ranking officer who, by virtue of formal rank, is allowed to speak on behalf of the organization.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but please note that on this site it is preferable to supply references (e.g. dictionary references) to support or substantiate an answer; otherwise it appears to be merely a personal opinion.  Also, please consider whether your answer adds anything to the answer already accepted 2 years ago.